# Reasoning behind SHA-3 state array indexing

Tags: sha-3, keccak

I was reading through the SHA3 standard (https://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202) and in the standard it defines how to construct 3D state array from a 1D array.

The state array is defined as follows:

> For all triples (x, y, z) such that 0 ≤ x < 5, 0 ≤ y < 5, and 0 ≤ z <
> w,
>
> A[x, y, z] = S [w(5y + x) + z]

This indexing is a bit cumbersome because in some sense, y > x > z (I can clarify what I mean if requested). I think it would be more natural to swap the x and y indices and defined it as:

> A[x,y,z] = S [w(5x + y) + z]

Is there a reason for the definition in the standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let us have a look at the state representation.

[image: state]

> For all triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $0 \le x < 5$, $0 \le y < 5$, and $0 \le z < w$, $$A[x,y,z]=S[w(5y+x)+z].$$
>   For example, if $b = 1600$, so that $w = 64$, then
>
> ```
> A[0,0,0] = S[0]     A[1,0,0] = S[64]     A[4,0,0] = S[256]
> A[0,0,1] = S[1]     A[1,0,1] = S[65]     A[4,0,1] = S[257]
> A[0,0,2] = S[2]     A[1,0,2] = S[66]     A[4,0,2] = S[258]
>
> A[0,0,61] = S[61]   A[1,0,61] = S[125]   A[4,0,61] = S[317]
> A[0,0,62] = S[62]   A[1,0,62] = S[126]   A[4,0,62] = S[318]
> A[0,0,63] = S[63]   A[1,0,63] = S[127]   A[4,0,63] = S[319]
>
> and
>
> A[0,1,0] = S[320]   A[1,1,0] = S[384]     A[4,1,0] = S[576]
> A[0,1,1] = S[321]   A[1,1,1] = S[385]     A[4,1,1] = S[577]
> A[0,1,2] = S[322]   A[1,1,2] = S[386]     A[4,1,2] = S[578]
>
> A[0,1,61] = S[381]  A[1,1,61] = S[445]    A[4,1,61] = S[637]
> A[0,1,62] = S[382]  A[1,1,62] = S[446]    A[4,1,62] = S[638]
> A[0,1,63] = S[383]  A[1,1,63] = S[447]    A[4,1,63] = S[639]
> ```

If you look into the position of the bits. you notice that you can consider your state as an array of $\texttt{u_int64}$ (numbering $0 \to 63$, $64 \to 127, \ldots$), this explains the $w$ in the formula.

**If you look at the ordering of the bits, you notice that we have the first plane ($y = 0$), then the second etc. Thus taking the 320 first bits select the first plane and so on.**

Now if you look at the operations in Keccak:

- $\iota$ operate on the lane $(0,0)$,
- $\theta$ operates on column but **depends on the parity of its neighbor columns**,
- $\pi$ and $\rho$ operates directly on the lane position
- **$\chi$ is applied to a row**.

**$\chi$ can also be seen as a 5-bits S-box that has been bit-sliced and to be applied $64$ times in parallel** (see bellow).

[image: chi]

We can thus select 320 bits and apply $\chi$ directly, the bits are grouped in such way that loading them consecutively will be fast (instead of fetching them at different positions). So we have a first reason to prefer this ordering.

Then we can have a look at $\theta$, it works mainly on columns but you can also consider doing it directly on planes (thus 320 times in parallel !).

[image: theta]

Thus selecting the states by bloc of 320 bits and adding them from a vector point of view makes it fast.

#### We thus have here two operations ($\theta$ and $\chi$) which benefit greatly from the $w(5y+x)+z$ ordering.

Now if you assume the other ordering ($w(5x+y)+z$), notice that:

- you have to fetch bits from 5 different position when you want to apply $\chi$.
- you can only work on $\theta$ with a parallelism over the column and not the slate anymore.

## TL;DR: $\chi$ and $\theta$ parallelism benefits a lot from this ordering (and also from a hardware point of view).

Comment: It took me some time to go through your answer carefully. It mostly makes sense to me.

Comment: @user668074 if the answer satisfies you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. :)